# Locking/controlling font size on mobile (HTML and/or CSS)

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

I have been updating my website and specifically trying to make it look better on mobile. Ideally, what I'd like to do is define exactly the font size on both desktop and mobile. I am happy with the body font size on desktop, but on mobile, it's a bit too small. I've tried playing with 'responsive text' code and the viewport tag, but nothing is to my liking (the margins get squeezed, the text looks good on one format but not the other, etc.). Am I able to define: (1) on desktop, font size is x, and (2) on mobile, font size is y? Site URL and CSS code below. Thank you in advance.

URL: https://www.domenictroiano.com/test.html

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {

p.text {

font-size: 30px;

}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 899px) {

p.text {

font-size: 60px;

}

}

#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked + .menu__btn > span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#menu__toggle:checked ~ .menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu__btn > span,
.menu__btn > span::before,
.menu__btn > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.menu__btn > span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}
.menu__btn > span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}
.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f0e68c;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #f9f5d1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Comment: Yes, it didn't achieve what I was looking for.

Comment: "(1) on desktop, font size is x, and (2) on mobile, font size is y?" media queries don't solve this how?

Comment: Please put the relevant code into your question and in particular show us how you reset the font size using media queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: CSS now saved in original post above (media queries at the top). The queries don't seem to impact font size on either device type.

Comment: You are missing the `<meta>` viewport element in your website to support responsive web design. Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to your website's `<head>`. You can read more about that at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: I added this code to the html head section and tried some different values for font-size, but this has no impact.